# Google StreetView: hide the link 'View on Google Maps'

Tags: css, google-maps

There is a link 'View on Google Maps' in StreetView, top left, which I need to hide. I have tried the following CSS which does not work:

```
.view-link {
     display:none !important;
}
```

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

After a lot more research this is the answer (I ran *Firebug* on *Firefox* to access the StreetView source code): Google have changed the class name from *view-link* as follows:

```
   .gm-iv-address-link {
        display:none !important;
   }
   .gm-iv-marker-icon {
        display:none !important;
   }
```

This removes both the link to Google Maps and any Icon link. I am using Maps v3.21 here.